# Tab bar controller displaying black area when clicking back to tab

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am experiencing a weird issue with my tab bar controller. I have a tabA which removes the navigation bar from the top. This is done through the View will load. When I click on Tab B I have the view load the navigation bar with a background. When I click back to tabA there is a black area at the bottom. I am guessing this is the space that because i added a bar after and when going back it takes it out its creating a mess. But i am not sure how to clean it up.
Here is my code:

Tab A:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.tabBarController setTitle:@" "];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Tab B:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.tabBarController setTitle:@"Tab B"];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tick Extended Edges **under opaque bars** on your view controller in storyboard

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now I have re added the navigation bar on the top and the black area at the bottom has gone away, if anybody finds the answer to this please let me know Thank you!